# Autowired vs import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am very new to spring boot and I am trying to grasp the concept of it. Now I came across @Autowired in it. I understood pretty much about it.

Like, when you write @Autowired, things happen in two passes and in the second pass spring injects beans.

Now, I have this example;

```
Class Abc {

    @Autowired
    private Xyz xyz;

    PSVM(String...z) {
        xyz.hello();
    } 
}
```

Import basically imports the code into the file.

So,

```
Import com.tilak.Xyz;

Class Abc {
    private Xyz xyz;

    PSVM(String...z) {
        xyz = new Xyz();
        xyz.hello();
    }
}
```

Why should/ shouldn't I go with the latter one?

Is there any advantage in doing the first one? Where should I use the first one and where should I use the second one?

Comment: spring framework comes with the idea of autowiring objects in place of creating objects in every occasion. As done in your code, it prevents extra code required.What do you mean by 'wrong'?

Comment: i mean , why would i go with the former one , why not the latter one? What's the benefit of doing th former one?

Comment: @Gimhani see the update

Comment: you do not need to explicitly initialize the object using constructor when you use spring @Autowired. This comes specially handy when you are working on a big java application.

Comment: You can read about the principle of the design pattern dependency injection at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its basically about object creation.
When you Autowire something, that particular bean is managed by the spring context and only one instance of particular class will be constructed by spring context and that particular instance will be provided when you use Autowire for that class type Objects. 
But when you import something into your class, that does not mean that you have an instance of that particular class; you have to initialize it on your own. And if you want to treat it as a singleton object, basically you will be writing whole code for it.

And more over there are basic differences between them like if you want to access static variables in a class, you will not need an instance of that class. (you can access them by class reference) In that case you dont need to Autowire but you need Import statement.

But on the other hand if you are interested in experiencing power of spring, like Autowire Configurations and may be validate them and all those cool functionalities that spring provides, you need to make your class a component and Autowire as you want.

Answer (score 6):

**I believe you are confusing Spring and the Java language.**

`Autowire` has to do with "Code injections". (Just like you described.) And is part of the Spring framework.

However, the `import` (with a lowercase i) is part of the Java language. As you stated, it makes other code available to be used in the class where you added it. `import` will be used regardless if you are using the Spring framework.

**Both of these statements have completely different purposes and are used with others.**

For example:
The class you are autowiring will also be imported (*if it is in a different Java package*). And you do not have to create an instance of it. In other words, you do not have to use the 'new' keyword - the Spring framework will do that for you. (*nice right?*)

But that being said, there is also a `@Import` annotation in the Spring framework, which is used for importing Spring Configuration classes. I am guessing this is where the confusion originated.